# How to sort a list in Python alphabetically by the index of the original list

Tags: python

I have a list:
**list_original= ['Zoe', 'Alex', 'Jennifer', 'Mike', 'Robert']**

How can I iterate through the indices of list_original in order to get the names alphabatically?
--> **['Alex', 'Jennifer', 'Mike', 'Robert', 'Zoe']**

Therefore I wanted to code a **for-loop**.

list_alphabetical = []

for i in ... :
list_alphabetical.append(i)

Could someone help? :)

Comment: Why don't you use sort function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python has a built in method called sorted which can help you. See [the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) for more details.

```
list_original= ['Zoe', 'Alex', 'Jennifer', 'Mike', 'Robert']
list_sorted = sorted(list_original)
print(list_sorted)
>>> ['Alex', 'Jennifer', 'Mike', 'Robert', 'Zoe']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
list_original= ['Zoe', 'Alex', 'Jennifer', 'Mike', 'Robert']
list_alphabetical = sorted(list_original)
```

Comment: No need to copy the original list because sorted() won't mutate the original list

Comment: Also no need to do `list(...)`. `sorted` already returns a list